How do I solve the Zip file size problem with installing the terra package in R
I'm having trouble installing the Terra R package. Below is the command I used and the response. I am on Windows 11
> install.packages("terra")
Installing package into 'C:/Users/blane/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/terra_1.7-71.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 39571680 bytes (37.7 MB)
downloaded 12.6 MB

Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  download from 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/terra_1.7-71.zip' failed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 13259769 != reported length 39571680
2: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/terra_1.7-71.zip': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package 'terra' failed

I expected Terra to be successfully installed .

This looks like a local problem for you.  You could try downloading the file using a browser, and then installing the local file, but that might not make any difference if your system is restricting the download size.

Possibly relevant (and many other similars).

Limey's reference had the solution. The 37MB file was not downloading in less that the 60 sec default time limit. The command 'options(timeout = max(1000, getOption("timeout")))' solved the problem
